# Is there a source for giving charity in round numbers plus one?

Tags: minhag, number, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tzedakah-charity

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40298/source-for-times-chai) asks about the (mostly?) Ashkenazic practice of giving charity in multiples of 18. Another custom I have observed is to give charity in round numbers + 1 e.g. $51, $101, $201 etc. This practice seems to be prevalent in the Syrian and Moroccan communities.

It looks like a gesture of acknowledgment that the cause deserves more than donation being given I'm sure every dollar helps, but is there a Torah-based source for it or is it purely cultural?

Comment: Hello Yitzchak. Interesting question. My former synagogue had a large population of people from the former Soviet Union. Many of them also donated in round numbers plus one.

Comment: This source suggests that it is a custom:  http://www.chafed.org/library/article_cdo/aid/484894/jewish/What-is-the-reason-giving-money-in-multiples-of-18.htm.

Comment: 126 also in my experience.

Comment: @JJLL, did you mean http://chabad.org/484894? But I don't see this there.

Comment: sources for 101 and 201 are gematria of the names of angels. See here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40802/6641