# When did the custom of giving charity in multiples of 18 begin?

Tags: number, tzedakah-charity

People often give charity in multiples of 18.

What is the earliest record of such donations?

Comment: Similar to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40298/source-for-times-chai. My question is asking for earliest record more than for a source... I know the 'chai' significance..

Comment: I don’t understand how this is different from the linked question, which asks for “the source for giving charity of the numeric value of the Hebrew word chai (18) and its multiples.”

Comment: Not looking so much for the source (although I added it into the question).. Looking mainly for earliest record of such donations.

Comment: Charity atones for sinning, so maybe that's why people give away in units of חטא, like ridding oneself of the sins.

Comment: @chortkov2 Wouldn’t the source necessarily be the earliest record?

Comment: DonielF - No. I highly doubt there will be a legitimate 'source' for the custom, but there may be some records of donations made in multiples of 18 that can help trace how far back the custom goes

Comment: I note, that Sefardic Jews have a custom of giving in multiples of 26, corresponding to the gematria of the name of Hashem הוי"ה.

Comment: On a lighter note, the story goes about a Satmar chassid, who gave the Rebbe a donation of $47. When asked about the unusual figure, he answered that it corresponded to the gematria of יוא"ל, which was the rebbes name.The rebbe answered, tongue in cheek, "In the "heim" they called me יואלי"ש!" (gematria 357!)

Comment: @IsraelReader I met a collector once who calmy said: "I don't want Chai, I want Mes."